# tableview not loadingg after segue back

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

So when I reach my CartViewController the table loads just fine but when I pass the segue back to it the table becomes empty!! My other TableViews in different controllers reload with the same code but this view controller is acting weird.

```
class MealsDetailsController: UIViewController , UITableViewDelegate , UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    getMeals()

}


func getMeals () {
    Alamofire.request(url!, method: .post, parameters: para,encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
        // get data code
        let info = Meals(meal_id: id, Logo: logoString, meal_name: name, price: price)    
        self.meals.append(info)
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

// what is going on here?
} else {

print("sorry data from api has some error")
}


}


}
```

Comment: Please update the class to which this code belongs, it hard to know which view controller's code is this !!?

Comment: this is all in CartViewController. I'm doing the api call and loading the table in one view controller @DarkInnocence

Comment: can you explain this line "when I pass it then segue back to it the table becomes empty!! " Perhaps upload a GIF to see it in action

Comment: I have 3 view controllers. 1 = main , 2= cart , 3= meal. when I go from main -> cart the table reloads just fine.. then I go to meal and press the back button, cart table isn't loading , it's just empty cells

Comment: @leo0019 do you have a segue going **back** from the `meal` to the `cart`?

Comment: from cart to meal by code. From meal to cart from the storyboard

Comment: Yeah, you cannot go **back** like this. You may think you're going back to the existing `cart` table but actually you are going to a new `cart` view.

Comment: so I should do 'perform segue' in the meal back to cart ?

Comment: Fogmeister is right.. It opens up a new instance of cart and not the previous one. To avoid this use Navigation controller or connect it with an unwind segue

Comment: @leo0019 no, that is using a segue. To go back it depends on how you went forward. If you're in a navigation controller then don't do anything. The back button will appear and it will go back properly. If you're not in a navigation controller then use `dismiss(viewController:)`

Comment: But still, even if he goes back and find tableview empty, how's that possible? The web service is getting hit even at the new instance

Comment: 'dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)' solves it

Comment: glad, we were starting to get worried.. :D

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if i understand your code correctly then You are calling main thread in outside of Alamofire.request function.Update your code like below

```
func  getMeals () {

Alamofire.request(url!, method: .post, parameters: para,encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in

// get data code
        let info = Meals(meal_id: id, Logo: logoString, meal_name: name, price: price)
        self.meals.append(info)
             DispatchQueue.main.async{
                 self.tableView.reloadData()
             }
    }

}
```

Comment: then plz check tableView datasource are called & check what returns in numberOfRows in section method.

Comment: I also agree with @DS Dharma that the update table operation was `outside` of Alamofire response block. What happen if your tableview reloads old data before the request finished --> Nothing changed.